# MongoDB: Query string returns different result when calling from .NET

Tags: c#, mongodb, nosql

I'm trying to construct a query string manually - however when calling 
Find() in my C# app it does not return any results. When calling 
through shell or MongoVue it does return expected results.

Is this internal limitation of the .NET driver? Does driver transform the 
string in some way before passing to Mongo?

Here is the query string:

```
{ 
   "Severity" : 2, 
   "Environment" : { "$elemMatch" : { 
       "Name" : "MachineName", "Value" : "XYZ" } }, 
   "Environment" : { "$elemMatch" : { 
      "Name" : "ApplicationName", "Value" : "ABC" } } 
}
```

Comment: Apparently, this query is invalid as second "Environment" overwrites the first one. Nevermind, sorry

Answer (score 1):

You've doubled-up `"Environment"`. You probably can't `and` these together. However, you may able to [`$or`](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%24or) these to get the expected behaviour.